# Finding function for data

Tags: graphing-functions, data-analysis

I'm in need of a function for this data which occurs in an application I am making. I've been staring at it for hours and I can't figure it out, hope someone here can help me.

Here's the data:
f(x) = y
f(1.25) = 4
f(1.5) = 2
f(2) = 1
f(3) = 0.5

Now I need to know what f does in order to get y here, I can see that for halving of x's steps the steps in y will double, but I and none of my collegues have any idea how to put this into a function.

I hope someone here can help (and I hope this is the right StackExchange Mathemematics)

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you need to find a function $f$ which fulfills the above equalities? Does the function have to be linear, or what does the first requirement mean? But a linear function cannot fulfill all the following requirements. Maybe you could try a piece-wise linear function.

Comment: I am looking to find a function that would fulfill all the above equalities. Problem is I got these numbers from software and I am not sure (after seeing Anastasios answer) if the equalities I have are true due to possible floating point errors in the software.
In fact I just need the data to be accurate between 1 and 3, whatever happens after that is not important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple function y(x) leads to the exact fit :
   y=1/(x-1)

Comment: Oh wow is it really this simple? This works for me so thanks everyone for the great brush-up on math, but this will work just fine!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried WolframAlpha for this?

You can use

```
"Fit (x1,y1),(x2,y2),...(xn,yn)"
```

[Here are the results](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fit%20%281.25,4%29,%20%281.5,2%29,%20%282,1%29,%20%283,0.5%29,%20%285,0.75%29)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Let's consider a sequence $a_n$ instead of $f(x)$. That makes the problem easier since the poster used only discrete values of $x$. If a continous function is needed that I am afraid that you need to use some fitting procedure as the previous answer has stated. Now the values of the $x_n, y_n$ that the OP has listed could be written in this way
$$
x_3=2-0.5-0.25-0.125=2-1/2-1/4-1/8 
$$
$$
x_2=2-0.5-0.25=2-1/2-1/4
$$
$$
x_1=2-0.5=2-1/2
$$
$$
x_0=2
$$
$$
x_{-1}=2+1
$$
$$
x_{-2}=2+1+2
$$
$$
x_{-3}=2+1+2+4
$$
and 
$$
y_3=8; y_2=4; y_1=2; y_0=1; y_{-1}=0.5; y_{-2}=0.25; y_{-3}=0.125
$$
this could be generalized in the following form (I need to try to write it in a general form, but I hope for now it will suffice)
$$
x_n=2-\sum_{m=1}^n\frac{1}{2^m}+\frac{1}{2}; n\ge 1
$$
and
$$
x_n=2+\sum_{m=0}^n\frac{1}{2^m}-1; n\le0
$$
I may have done some mistakes, so if you spot any, please let me know :-)
and then
$$
y_n=2^n
$$

*EDIT*: I tried the FIT function as suggested in wolframalpha and got not very nice results for polynomial or logarithmic function

[image]

Comment: Does this mean the data that I got from my application is incorrect? I mean I can see the pattern in the data, but I don't understand why it has to be so difficult to get a proper function for it that provides the correct answers for each of those points.

Comment: Can I ask you how you get the data? Why you get it in discrete form in power of $2$? Maybe if you describe how you get it we could understand more... It seems you are getting the data from a set of discrete operations. Am I right?